# Is it likely that a London office of a US-based broker will have an SEC Officer 'in-house'?

Tags: fraud, scams, sec

Is it likely that the London office of a US-based broker will have an SEC Officer 'in-house'?

This is in regard to confirming a purchase with the company. The call time was between 3am and 4am London time. I am in Australia.

Company describe themselves as an 'Alternative Asset Manager':
"a leading global alternative asset manager, focused on investing in long-life, top-notch assets across technology, infrastructure, renewable power and equity that is private". They claim to have a block of shares to sell to investors at a favourable price.

Comment: SEC as in *US* SEC?

Comment: Yes, claimed to be from the US SEC, seconded to the office during a very active period for the on-selling of the shares.

Comment: Just edited title and body to reflect that the company is US based and this is the London office.

Comment: What exactly is a ‘favorable’ price? If they claim they offer them under market price, it’s a scam.

Comment: They claim to have a block of shares that they are selling in small numbers to attract new investors/clients. The price was below market on the day, by about 8%.

Comment: This is setting off all sorts of alarm bells, just to be clear; they called you right?

Comment: Something smells bad here. Googling your phrase leads to Liberty Global Partners, which yes has a pretty website so appears to *exist*; however, their Companies House filing shows the UK company was set up on 12 July *this year* and has *one* director who owns all the shares. Which does not sound *at all* like how an actual international brokerage might be set up.

Comment: @Koen vd H, yes, they initially contacted me.

Comment: @AakashM Glad you were able to see the Companies House filing. I could not, even though I ended up there several times.

Comment: This has Boiler Room scam written all over it http://citywire.co.uk/money/how-to-spot-a-boiler-room-scam/a462793 What evidence do you have that it isn't?

Comment: I have no evidence that it is not. I found the description of Boiler Room scam in Australian Gov website. I agree that it is this scam.

Answer (score 6):

I have worked for an alternative asset manager that had SEC personal in the office when the SEC was doing their semi-periodic audits.  I'll mention they showed up at 8am and left at 5pm as if they had a clock set.  This was just my experience.

It seems unlikely but not out of the realm of reason that someone from the SEC would be in a US company's London office.  It seems rather unlikely that a firm would tell someone about the SEC presence over the phone.  If I recall, we were asked to not mention the presence of SEC to anyone outside the firm while they were there.  I'm not sure if that was company policy or an SEC request.

I don't work for the SEC so don't take this as an answer.  I'd call the SEC.  They may be able to confirm the presence and they may be interested in a US firm that would use their name in a sales call.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I intend to call the SEC directly during business hours.
It was the suspicion of an SEC officer working overnight that led me to post this question.

Comment: You say when the SEC was auditing the company. This was describe as being to speak with new clients and validate that they understood what was being implemented - new client, new account, value of investment etc.

Comment: Yeah this sounds super fishy to me, but I don't work for the SEC so I can't be sure.